# Magmi image uploader

Tags: magmi, ce-1.9.0.1

I keep getting this error from the Image attributes processor v1.0.25

plugin;ImageAttributeItemProcessor;warning:Image attributes processor v1.0.25 - error copying media/catalog/product/g/e/getimage_new.asp_id_801875_imagetype_2_noimagetype_2_colorimagesize_3_lineartimagesize_3 : download error,URL https://images.truevalue.com/getimage_new.asp?id=801875&ImageType=2&NoImageType=2&ColorImageSize=3&LineArtImageSize=3 is unreachable

What does this mean and how can I fix it!

**EDIT**

When I go to http://images.truevalue.com/ I get the following.

Directory Listing Denied

This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

Could this be the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check that the URL is actually available via your browser. If so. You should check your magento server php configuration for remote_url_fopen that it's enabled and try again. 
Also. Try to create a test script on the server that performs file_get_contents and see the results

Comment: It is available to the browser... You can click on it and the image comes up. The php config for remote_url_fopen is enabled. I have gotten images from other URLS. Only this one has given me this error.

Comment: Well that's all I can do without seeing the actual csv and magmi configurations. Sorry